# how to acess data from axious post request on node backend?

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to send a data object to backend using axios... the question is should I use axios at back end as well ? I don't seem to be able to get the value.

```js
 axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/encrypt',
      data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone',
      },
      //headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'}
    });
```

```js
app.post('/encrypt', (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body, 'Request................');
});
```

Comment: request.body.firstName  and request.body.lastName

Comment: I think you are mixing two things - axios is client side and from your code snippet looks like you are trying expressjs for your server. And while it should work to just log the request.body I was seeing the same behavior with a simple express server. If you add `res.send(req.body)`  you will see the body you posted sent back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the body parser.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// create application/json parser
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json()

app.post('/encrypt', jsonParser, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

And the client side

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/encrypt',
      data: {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone',
      },
      //headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ...'}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your code and write according to the syntax.
Axios returns a promise.

```
axios.post('/encrypt', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone' }
).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: I did this the issue is I need to access the firs name and last name on server yet there is no reference for them oddly I am getting a response

Comment: Did you write : request.body.firstName, request.body.lastName?